# Cannot deserialize text when character "&#016" is found

Tags: c#, encoding, deserialization, control-characters

I have a .net application that tries to deserialize a string using .net serializer.
But looks like my serializer fails when &#016 is found in the text.

XML:

```
<MyMessage>
   <MyObjectMessage messageId="30_636529918974765415">
     <body>&#016</body>
   </MyObjectMessage> 
</MyMessage>
```

C# Code:

```
var InvalidFile = @"C:\Users\jacjosep.ORADEV\Desktop\trial.xml";
ChatMessage responseMessage = null;
var chatSerilalizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(InvalidFile, FileMode.Open))
{
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
   {
      try
      {
         responseMessage = (chatSerilalizer.Deserialize(reader) as MyObject);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      { 
         throw ex;
      }

    }

}
```

Comment: So what is the exception? "Looks like my serializer fails" is not a good error report.

Comment: (And it sounds like that's invalid XML to me anyway - so what's created it, and can you fix *that* so that you don't get invalid XML any more?)

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: _Never_ make a try-catch block that just does `throw ex;`. The only thing that does is destroying the exception's stack trace, since that's (re)generated at the point where it's thrown. If you want to process the error there but still propagate it, use `throw;` without the `ex` behind it.

Answer (score 7):

That's not valid xml.

A decimal character reference would be semicolon terminated, such as `&#016;` - and even with the semicolon, that would be code-point 16 "data link escape" - which some tools will reject; note from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML) that in XML 1.0, the only control characters allowed are U+0009 (tab), U+000A (line-feed) and U+000D (carriage return).

So: ask whoever provided you with that file to kindly provide valid well-formed XML, preferably XML 1.0. It may help to prepend the xml with `<?xml version="1.1"?>`, *if* you have XML 1.1 compatible tooling. AFAIK: the .NET XML tools are 1.0-based.